# Add logging listener for whole test suite

Tags: logging, junit

I am using JUnit4 and organized all my tests in a Test suite, annotated with a @RunWith(Suite.class) annotation.

Now I want to register a custom logger to JUnit, so at each beginning and completion of each test a log message is printed.

I already found the RunNotifier and RunListener classes, but don't know how I can add my listener from within my TestSuite definition to JUnit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've already hinted at the solution. Write your own runner and use the @RunWith annotation to specify your runner for your test/suite. That should allow you to see your output even when running in eclipse/ant as junit will use the annotation.

Comment: +1 This is so easy that I don't know why I didn't thought about it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate a [JUnitCore](http://api.dpml.net/junit/4.2/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html) object and call addListener() before calling run.  Not sure if there is a better way with an annotation, but I haven't come across one.

Comment: The problem is here that I start my UnitTests from Eclipse, so I don't instantiate the JUnitCore for myself. In addition, I want to start the tests from ant, and want the same logging behaviour.

Comment: In Eclipse, you could just call the main method by running as a Java app.  In Ant, it's not that simple, because you wouldn't want to lose the junit reporting.  Maybe see how ant adds the junitreport listener and add both?  This doesn't seem like the best way though.

Comment: I want to use the eclipse GUI to run tests, so I can's just start the Test for myself (I know how to do that and already wrote my own runner, but now I just want a possibility to configure my tests, so that starting and ending of tests is logged).

Comment: I think you are going to need to create your own runner which adds the listeners on your behalf.  That way it still works in Eclipse GUI and (Ant/Maven) if need be.